# How to prepend ArrayList to another ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am looking to **prepend** the elements of a `java.util.ArrayList` L1 to another `java.util.ArrayList` L2 and I cannot find an out of the box way to do it. I do not want to create a third ArrayList and hack around as L2 is the List being used in the view layer. Neither `java.util.Collections` nor `org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils` has such a utility method (as far as I can see).

How can I efficiently prepend an ArrayList to another ArrayList, using existing API preferably ? For a java 7 environment.

P.S: `addAll` appends, I want to prepend.

Comment: So you're trying to take 1 ArrayList, then add it's contents at the beginning of the other?

Comment: @FailingCoder Yes. Updated the question for more clarity

Comment: happybuddha wants to addAll it to the beginning of the list without another arraylist

Comment: @FailingCoder so use `L2.addAll`

Comment: Note that `List#addAll(Collection)` appends but `List#addAll(int,Collection)` can insert at any valid index, including `0` which will prepend the `Collection`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`List#addAll(int,Collection)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#addAll(int,java.util.Collection)):

> Inserts all of the elements in the specified collection into this list at the specified position (optional operation). Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right (increases their indices). The new elements will appear in this list in the order that they are returned by the specified collection's iterator. The behavior of this operation is undefined if the specified collection is modified while the operation is in progress. (Note that this will occur if the specified collection is this list, and it's nonempty.)

If you use `0` as the index it will prepend the given `Collection` to the `List`. For example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

        list1.add("Item #1");
        list1.add("Item #2");

        list2.add("Item #3");
        list2.add("Item #4");

        System.out.println("List #1: " + list1);
        System.out.println("List #2: " + list2);

        list2.addAll(0, list1);

        System.out.println("Combined List: " + list2);

    }
}
```

Output:

```
List #1: [Item #1, Item #2]
List #2: [Item #3, Item #4]
Combined List: [Item #1, Item #2, Item #3, Item #4]
```

Comment: As I said in previous answers, it is a costly operation to add elements at 0th position

Comment: @PraveenE Of course it is. However, the OP wants to prepend a list to another list without using a third list. At least `#addAll(int,Collection)` can optimize the process, unlike using `#add(int,E)` in a loop. With an `ArrayList`, most likely `#addAll(int,Collection)` will only need to perform one shift and then one iteration.

Comment: @PraveenE it's not costly, because it uses `System.arraycopy` inside (for ArrayLists)

Comment: Oh then it should be fine. Thanks @KirillSimonov

Answer (score 7):

`subList` gives you a view into a list. If you make a view at the very start of the list, `addAll` will do the right thing.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("extant1", "extant2"));
ArrayList<String> prefix = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("prefix1", "prefix2"));

list.subList(0, 0).addAll(prefix);
list
// => list ==> [prefix1, prefix2, extant1, extant2]
```

Comment: This is clever, but why not just use `List#addAll(int,Collection)` with `0` as the index? [It seems to do what the OP wants.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58479837/6395627)

Comment: @Slaw: Because I missed that signature :D I endorse your answer as the better one.

Answer (score 0):

Checking [docs.oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) showed me one function. `ArrayList.add(int index, E element)` This helps, because you can place the items of the ArrayList at the beginning of the array, for example:

```
ArrayList <Integer> L1 = {2, 3, 5, 7} /*Imaginary declaration*/, L2 = {500, 600}; 
for(int i=0; i<L1.size(); i--) L2.add(0, L1.get(i));
```

But this will leave L2 with {7, 5, 3, 2, 500, 600} because each element added at index [0] will push the next ones forward. Instead, do it the opposite way:
`for(int i=L1.size()-1; i>=0; i++) L2.add(0, L1.get(i));`

Comment: This will be a costly operation. Everytime we add element at 0th index, all the elements after it will be moved. This operation will be beneficial only if L2 is a linked list

Comment: Just went through the implementation of add method based on comments in other answers. I think it is ok to do it. It internally uses System Arraycopy

Comment: @FailingCoder Note you should have `i--` in your "reverse for loop" instead of `i++`.

Comment: @PraveenE Using `add(0, element)` over and over in a loop will still be costly since the `ArrayList` is forced to do an `arraycopy` _for each call_. If we must prepend an entire `Collection` to a `List` we should use `List#addAll(int,Collection)` because it allows the implementation to optimize the call (e.g. `ArrayList` will likely only need to call `arraycopy` _one time_). Of course, you're correct that prepending an element to an `ArrayList` will in general be more costly than appending the element. A `LinkedList` should hardly notice a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any particular inbuilt function that can do this thing. Here is the trick I am following to solve this.
If L1 is {1,2} and L2 is {3,4} then

1. Reverse the list L1 (It will become {2,1} )
2. Iterate the list L2 from back and add the
   elements to L1. (You can also reverse L2 and do addAll on L1. If you
   are ok with modifying L2, do it) (L1 will become {2,1,4,3} )
3. Reverse the list L1 (L1 will become {3,4,1,2} )

Total Time Complexity : O(m+n) where m is size of L1 and n is size of L2

```
        List<Integer> li1 = new ArrayList<>();
        li1.add(1);
        li1.add(2);

        List<Integer> li2 = new ArrayList<>();
        li2.add(3);
        li2.add(4);

        Collections.reverse(li1);
        ListIterator<Integer> listIterator = li2.listIterator(li2.size());
        while (listIterator.hasPrevious())
        {
            Integer previous = listIterator.previous();
            li1.add(previous);
        }
        Collections.reverse(li1);
        System.out.println(li1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply You can do this way:

```
List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> l2 = new ArrayList<>();

l1.add("a");
l1.add("b");

l2.add("c");
l2.add("d");

l1.addAll(l2);

System.out.println(l1); // if you want result in list 1

l2.clear();

l2.addAll(l1);

System.out.println(l2); // if you want result in list 2
```

Comment: I see no problem with this - can even assign `l1 = l2` if necessary.

Comment: l1=l2 not recommended because you are assigning l2 reference to l1 now both pointing to same reference, So in future if you want to change l1 or l2 (any one) both gets effected.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use  Collections.addAll​(int index, Collection c)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

            List<String> orginalList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList( "E","F","G","H"));
            System.out.println(orginalList);

            Collections.reverse(orginalList);

            List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList( "A","B","C","D"));
            System.out.println(newList);

            Collections.reverse(newList);
            orginalList.addAll(newList);

            Collections.reverse(orginalList);
            System.out.println(orginalList);



        }
```